# Joomla module Kunena latest Fatal Error

Tags: php, joomla

I am using the Kunena Component v 2.0.4 and the Kunena Latest Module 1.7.2 in my Joomla 1.7 website. The Kunena Component works fine but the module gives the following error on the front end:

> Fatal error: Class 'KunenaModule' not found in /home/content/xx/xxxxxx/html/en/modules/mod_kunenalatest/class.php on
>   line 15

Here are the first lines of the file class.php

```
defined ( '_JEXEC' ) or die ();
class ModuleKunenaLatest extends KunenaModule {
    static protected $css = '/modules/mod_kunenalatest/tmpl/css/kunenalatest.css';
    protected function _display() {
        // Load language files.
        KunenaFactory::loadLanguage('com_kunena.sys', 'admin');
        KunenaFactory::loadLanguage();
        KunenaFactory::loadLanguage('com_kunena.templates');
        // Convert module parameters into topics view parameters
        $categories = $this->params->get ( 'category_id', 0 );
        $categories = is_array($categories) ? implode(',', $categories) :     $categories;
        $this->params->set('limitstart', 0);
        $this->params->set('limit', $this->params->get ( 'nbpost',5 ));
        $this->params->set('topics_categories', $categories);
        $this->params->set('topics_catselection', $this->params->get (      'sh_category_id_in', 1 ));
        $this->params->set('topics_time', $this->params->get (     'show_list_time', 168 ));
        $userid = 0;
```

Comment: **Kunena 2.x = out of date** ... **Kunena Latest Module 1.7.2 = out of date** ... **Joomla 1.7 = out of date**. Please update Kunena to 3.0.5 and your Joomla site to 2.5

Comment: Hi, i also tried it to joomla 2.5 and still getting the same error